# Sending SMS with GSM Modem from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sms, serial-port, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

I want to send SMS using GSM modem's AT-Commands from SQL Server 2008, so I wrote a Visual C# SQL CLR Database Project and a stored procedure.

But when I execute that stored procedure I received this error:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

The source codes of stored procedure and the class for sending sms are these:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void SendSMS2(string phone, string message)
{
    SMSManagement.SM2S ss = new SMSManagement.SM2S();
    ss.SendMessage(phone, message);
}

public void SendMessage(string PhoneNumber, string Message)
{
    try
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort();

        port.PortName = "COM5";                
        port.BaudRate = 115200;                  
        port.DataBits = 8;                
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;     
        port.Parity = Parity.None;        
        port.ReadTimeout = 300;           
        port.WriteTimeout = 300;          

        // Error occurred in here.
        port.Open();
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;

        SMS sms = new SMS();
        sms.Direction = SMSDirection.Submited;
        sms.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
        sms.ValidityPeriod = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0, 0);
        sms.Message = Message;

        Message = sms.Compose(SMS.SMSEncoding.UCS2);

        ExecCommand(port, "AT", 300, "No phone connected");
        ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=0", 300, "Failed to set pdu format.");
        ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGS=1", 300, "Failed to set message length.");
        string command = Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26);
        ExecCommand(port, command, 6000, "Failed to send message"); 

        port.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The version of Visual Studio and SQL Server is 2010 SP1 and 2008 R2.
The CLR project framework is 2.0 .

Comment: How did you install the CLR assembly into SQL Server?? What command and what settings did you use??

Comment: I deploy it to my database in SQL Server and I show it in Assemblies list.

Comment: Yes - sure - but **HOW** do you deploy it?? Directly from Visual Studio?? Then see my answer and check your settings. Or do you deploy it with a T-SQL script (`CREATE ASSEMBLY ......`) - then please show us that script!

Comment: I deploy it directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: BAD title- has NOTHING to do with GSM modems. This is "how to access serial port from c procedure in sql server". Your title is misleading as hell. Your problem is not relaetd to the modem at all.

Comment: @TomTom: My problem is not "how to access serial port from c procedure in sql server". My problem is described in content of the question, I know how to access serial port but when I open the serial port I received error.

Comment: Yes, and the descriptio nsi a SECURITS VIOLATION ACCESSING THE SERIAL PORT. Ups. Did you read what you wrote? Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. - not allowed to access an unmanaged resource. What is attached is irrelevant.

Comment: How to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention how you installed your assembly into SQL Server. If you just deployed straight from Visual Studio - what permission level did you specify??

[image]

The default value is `Safe`, which is okay as long as you only work within SQL Server - regex matching or things like that.

If you want to "reach out" from SQL Server and communicate with the world, you **must** set the `Permission Level` to `Unsafe` before you deploy your assembly into SQL Server.

Comment: I changed it, but on deploy I received this error: Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 10327, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'SMSManagement' failed because assembly 'SMSManagement' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.  The assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the database owner (DBO) has UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.

Comment: @ABI: so did you check that those requirements are met?? Does your database owner have that permission needed? Does the database have that `TRUSTWORTHY` flag set??

Comment: I set TRUSTWORTHY flag but I received "The database owner SID recorded in the master database differs from..." error. I fixed this error. Now that work fine. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to deploy it at my server. can you help https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29101991/Send-SMS-in-mssql.html?anchor=a42579208&notificationFollowed=208109441#a42579208